# How to align text in a list in columns

Tags: macos, swiftui

I have a few objects with text attributes that I want to write out in a list and I can't figure out how to align the different atts in columns. I just want each element to be .leading aligned.

The offset here dont work as it offsets relative to the previous word on the line.

```
var body: some View {
    VStack{
        
        List(students) { student in
            HStack{
                Text(student.name!)
                Text(student.age!).offset(x: 10, y: 0)
                Text(student.adress!).offset(x: 20, y: 0)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: which OS? and how do you want them to be aligned?

Comment: It’s MacOS. I’d like to have the elements aligned by leading edge.

Comment: macOS has `Table` for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks, I’ll check it out

Comment: You can also use the `.frame` modifier on `Text`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Asperi I found this in the documentation:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/table

```
structq Person: Identifiable {
    let givenName: String
    let familyName: String
    let id = UUID()
}
private var people = [
    Person(givenName: "Juan", familyName: "Chavez"),
    Person(givenName: "Mei", familyName: "Chen"),
    Person(givenName: "Tom", familyName: "Clark"),
    Person(givenName: "Gita", familyName: "Kumar"),
]

var body: some View {
    Table(people) {
        TableColumn("Given Name", value: \.givenName)
        TableColumn("Family Name", value: \.familyName)
    }
}
```